# Trying to pull table header field using closest and .find functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatable

I am trying to pull the header field on a table so that I can manually adjust the size of the  field. The header that I am trying to get to has the  data-dynatable-column of **"paymentStatus"**.  Here is the function that checks for each  tied to a particular table:

```
  $("#DetCheckResults td").each(function () {

             var xyzh = $(this).html();
             var tdId = $(this).closest('th').find(".dynatable-head").text();   

             alert("Value of tdId field is " + tdId) ;

              xyzh = xyzh.replace(/,/g, "");

               if ($.isNumeric(xyzh))
               {

                  $(this).css("text-align", "right");
               }                                                  

              if (tdId === "paymentStatus") 
              {

                  $(this).css("width", "10%");
              }        
           });
```

Here is a description of the table:

```
      <table class="tablesaw tablesaw-stack table-responsive" id="detailCheck_search_results" data-tablesaw-mode="stack">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="dynatable-head" data-dynatable-column="transmittal"><a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">Transmittal</a></th>
            <th class="dynatable-head" data-dynatable-column="naid"><a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">NAID</a></th>
            <th class="dynatable-head" data-dynatable-column="transmittalTotal"><a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">Transmittal Total</a></th>
            <th class="dynatable-head" data-dynatable-column="checkNumber"><a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">Check Number</a></th>
            <th class="dynatable-head" data-dynatable-column="payeeId"><a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">Payee ID</a></th>
            <th class="dynatable-head" data-dynatable-column="paymentStatus"><a class="dynatable-sort-header" href="#">Payment Status</a></th>
       </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>                                                       
             <tr>
                 <td style="text-align: left;">SFF CB 16 00005</td>
                 <td style="text-align: left;">CASANDI500</td>
                 <td style="text-align: right;">7,181.42</td>
                 <td style="text-align: right;">403053601263</td>
                 <td style="text-align: left;">XXXXX0934</td>
                 <td style="text-align: left;">A</td>
             /tr> 
        /table>
```

Can you look at the definition of the 'tdId' field to see how I can pull the  header correctly.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are traversing the table dom incorrectly.  The th element you are looking for is not a direct ancestor of the td you are operating on.

You need to do:

```
$(this).closest("table").find("th").eq($(this).index());
```

and to reference the data-id you need to do:

```
tdId.data("dynatable-column") === "paymentStatus"
```

See this jsfiddle (I change the style change to a color to easily see the change)

https://jsfiddle.net/algorithmicMoose/p3L3bov2/